# React-Router: Infinite/Dynamic nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

As a proof of concept, I'm working on an application that supports infinite navigation; that is, each page has a list of links (passed in as props from the parent) and you can keep clicking into each subsequent page with no end.

This would result in a url that looks like: `mypage/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/...` as you keep navigating further and further into the application. What I'm unclear about is how to dynamically generate an infinite number of routes in react router. I know that using react-router, you can dynamic load routes, a lazy-load approach, but I can't quite figure out how to keep generating deeper and deeper routes.

I had some ideas:

- Store the nested routing state inside redux and use that in conjunction with dynamic routing
- pattern match a route with `/**` (untested)

Comment: The latter sounds like the only reasonable and possible solution to me.

Comment: Have you come up with any decent pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [JsFiddle that demonstrates infinite nesting](https://jsfiddle.net/yqbqu0y9/). It uses the [Navigation router](http://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/) instead of the React Router but I hope you're open to that. You can see that, instead of manually building the Url, I'm passing an array and letting the Navigation router take care of building the Url for me. Each time the Hyperlink's clicked I add a new number to the array which increases the Url length. If you've got any questions about the code, please let me know.

```
// Pass an array for the parts parameter
// Each item in the array represents a segment of the Url
var Add = ({parts, stateNavigator}) => (
  <div>
    <div>Url: {stateNavigator.stateContext.url}</div>
    <div>Clicking Add increases the Url by one each time</div>
    <NavigationReact.RefreshLink
      navigationData={{parts: parts.concat(parts.length)}}
      stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
      Add
    </NavigationReact.RefreshLink>
  </div>
)

// The * indicates the parts parameter is a splat
// Splats can have infinite segments
var stateNavigator = new Navigation.StateNavigator([
  {key:'infinite', route:'{*parts}', defaults: {parts: [0]}}
]);

// When the infinite state is navigated to render the Add component
// Pass in the current parts data in the props
stateNavigator.states.infinite.navigated = function(data) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Add parts={data.parts} stateNavigator={stateNavigator} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
}

stateNavigator.start('/0');
```